# convergence of infinite series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(1+1/2+1/3+...+1/n)}{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to prove that below infinite series is convergent 
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1+1/2+1/3+...+1/n)}{n}$$

Edit : as pointed out the series is divergent and hence my approach is wrong

My approach :

I tried to approach it by Dirichlet convergence theorem by taking $u_{n}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+...+\frac{1}{n}\right) $  and $v_{n}=\frac{1}{n}$

but got struck at how to prove that the sum of $u_{n}$ upto  n terms is bounded  (if at all it is).

Earlier I had tried Ratio test through whichI was getting $\frac{u_{n}}{u_{n+1}}=1$ and thus failing the test .

Please let me know how can I approach this problem .

Comment: It doesn't look like convergent. Eact term is bounded below by $\frac{1}{n}$ and the harmonic series clearly diverges.

Comment: Surely you didn't mean to start at $n=0$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out I corrected it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Your series does not converge**. Clearly, you have that
$$\color{red}{1 + \frac12+...+\frac1n \geq 1}$$
for all $n\geq 1$. Hence, by comparison
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\color{red}{1+1/2+...+1/n}}{n}\geq \sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\color{red}{1}}{n}$$
The right hand side diverges to $\infty$ as $N\to\infty$ and is known as the Harmonic series. Your series is strictly larger by comparison and hence also diverges to $\infty$.

Comment: yes Thanks , I failed to see this I will edit the question

Comment: @kira0705 If you made a mistake in your question, instead create a new question. (This site discourages completely changing the question after answers have been given)

Comment: okay , should I add under edit that the series should be divergent , without changing the question entirely ?

Comment: @kira0705 Yes, it's fine to change that series should be divergent. I'm simply saying if you wrote the completely wrong series or something like that, then rather ask in a new question.

Answer (score 5):

The general term of your series is equivalent to 
$$\frac{\ln(n)}{n}$$

which is the general term of a divergent series. Therefore, your series diverges.

Comment: Thanks , I will make an edit to the question

Answer (score 0):

By summation by parts

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{H_n}{n} = H_N^2 - \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}\frac{H_n}{n+1} $$
hence
$$ -\frac{H_N}{N+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{H_n}{n} = H_N^2-\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{H_{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+1}}{n+1}$$
and
$$ -\frac{H_N}{N+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{H_n}{n}+\sum_{n=2}^{N+1}\frac{H_n}{n}=H_N^2+\sum_{n=2}^{N+1}\frac{1}{n^2}, $$

$$ 2\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{H_n}{n}=H_N^2+\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n^2}, $$
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{H_n}{n}=\frac{H_N^2+H_N^{(2)}}{2}=\frac{1}{2}\log^2 N+\gamma\log N+\frac{\gamma^2+\zeta(2)}{2}+O\left(\frac{\log N}{N}\right) $$
as $N\to +\infty$.

Answer (score -1):

Consider the partial sum of the given series.
1, 1/2, 11/18, 25/48...

By doing some calculation we have show that the sequence of partial sums form an non-increasing sequence and it is clearly bounded below (bounded also). Thus , this sequence of partial sums is convergent.
So that the given series is convergent.

Edit: 
I have noticed that made a mistake. This series is diverges.
Thanks to Thesilver doe.

Comment: Well, it's explicitely written in the post that the author made a mistake and the series is divergent... as explained in the other answers.

Comment: Can you point out my mistake? I am unable to find it.

Comment: Well, I don't know which "calculation" you did, but of course the sequence of partial sums is non decreasing ! The terms of your series are all positive, so the sequence of partial is obviously increasing.

Comment: I have got like this.  Let S(n) be the n th partial sum of the given series.   I have got that. S(n)-S(n+1)= 1/2 + 1/3 +...+1/(n+1) >0.  Thus it is decreasing sequence.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Not increasing. You should note the denominator

Comment: You are making a confusion between the sequence of the general terms of the series (that is $\frac{1+\frac{1}{2} + ... \frac{1}{n}}{n}$, which is indeed decreasing) and the sequence of the partial sums of that series, which is increasing.

Comment: Example : the series $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, whereas its general term $\frac{1}{n}$ decreases to $0$. But the sequences of partial sums is increasing to $+\infty$.

Comment: Yes I got it. Thanks much. I made a mistake.